# C# Type casting base class / interface vs. generic method

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

Say I have a simple inheritance structure with a shared interface:

```
public interface IMammal
{
  ...
}

public class Human : IMammal
{
  ...
}

public class Animal : IMammal
{
  ...
}
```

And say in a different class (Main.cs or whatever), I want to implement a method.  Which of the following is the "best practice":

```
public void MyFunction(IMammal input)
{
   // Do cool things with the IMammal.
}
```

Or

```
public void MyFunction<T>(T input) where T : IMammal
{
   // Do the same cool things with the IMammal.
}
```

Note: A possible solution in this simple case would be to make IMammal an abstract class and implement MyFunction in that abstract class.  I need to keep the IMammal an interface though.

Comment: It depends, do you need to know the particular *type* of mammal being passed in? For instance, do you need to *return* the same type of mammal? If not I would just go with the base class approach, `(Mammal input)`.

Comment: Note that `Animal : Mammal` is not correct in reality - most animals are not mammals.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice would usually to be the first case, and let the polymorphic behaviour of the underlying runtime handle types for you. Unless you specifically *need* to know the type (and as a generic!) it's best not to pass that around.

the case for the second option comes in when you're going to be making calls to other methods which need to be generic, such as those manipulating collections or serialization, and which must deal with `T` instead of the actual type of the object. This however is very rare and very specific behaviour, so it's better to use it only as absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what `MyFunction` *does*.  If `MyFunction` works just as designed without generics then leave it that way - using polymorphism is generally cleaner that introducing generics.  If you get to a point where using generics is beneficial (e.g. like adding to a `List<T>` rather than a `List<Mammal>` then switch to generics.

Create code that *works*, then focus on making it *better*.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better the first one, I mean than if you are calling other class you should pass the interface instead a class.

```
public void MyFunction(Mammal input)
{
   // Do cool things with the mammal.
}
```

Also it's better to cal interface IMammal instead Mammal.

That's because MyFunction is a method of another class, according to best practices it's better to inject an Interface instead an object.

Comment: Good call on the IMammal.  I originally had it as an abstract class but changed to an interface for simplicity.  I'll update that.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case, I would in general opt in for the first option.

However, for more complex scenarios, 2nd option is better because it allows you to further specify the type constraints, such as inheriting from multiple interfaces, or a class and an interface etc.
It will also for example allow you to instantiate new T objects, if you also include `new()` in the method's `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I see two implementations are equivalent. Then simple be the best, so option #1 I prefer.

If MyFunction is a behavior of Mammal, it should be in the interface. If you do some validation eg and requires something else from a higher layer for ex, put it in other class should be nice.